# Centos 5.4 - ls command not showing files on ftp server

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, ls

I have installed ftp and vsftpd on my CentOS 5.4 through `yum install ftp` and `yum install vsftpd`. I have also created one ftp user with `adduser ftpuser` command.

And here comes my problem.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ftp localhost
Connected to localhost.localdomain.
220 (vsFTPd 2.0.5)
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
530 Please login with USER and PASS.
KERBEROS_V4 rejected as an authentication type
Name (localhost:root): ftpuser
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,103,134)
150 Here comes the directory listing.
226 Directory send OK.
ftp>
```

Once after I login to my ftp server with `ftp localhost` command and try to see the files with ls command it is not showing any.

P.S: vsftpd service is running and I have placed some files in my ftp folder also. I have seen people asking the same question on various blogs but no where I got the answer. Please help me.

Comment: There aren't any files. Why would you expect to see something that doesn't exist?

Comment: Did you create any files/directories in ftpusers's home directory ?

Comment: @Michael Hampton Please read last two lines in my question. I have created files in my ftp directory. If I go to /home/ftpuser I can see my files.

Comment: @Iain I do created files.

Answer (score 1):

This will happen if there are no files that FTP can see (if memory serves, vsFTPd honours the convention of not showing files beginning with `.`; you can get around this by specifying `ls -a`).  The working directory may not be what you expect.

Use the pwd command to determine the working directory, and verify that there are files in there.  Consider uploading a file and checking that it shows up afterward (it will).